# Big trouble by trying to implement an Background Agent for WP8 App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I have a common Library 'DataLib':

```
namespace DataLib
{
public class DataLib
{
    public async static Task<List<String>> Daten()
    {
        //here is a http request witch call data from the internet in write it to file within isoStorage
        //than the content of this files will be written into var1, var2, var3... to return them at the end

        //than I creat an instans of an UserControl witch generate Images to the IsoStore using data from the IsoStore genarated at the beginning...
        var TestTile = new Tiles();

        //...and the tile will be updated here with the image form the isoStorage

        return new List<String> { var1, var2 var3 ... };
    }
}
```

The UserControll 'Tiles' looks like this:

```
namespace DataLib
{
    public partial class Tiles : UserControl
    {
        public Tiles()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //some stuff to generate the image and write it into isoStorage
        }    
    }
}
```

Within the app I am using var1, var2, var3... like this:

```
private async void Hauptfunktion()
{
    List<String> DatenPacket = await DataLib.DataLib.Daten();
    string var1 = DatenPacket[0].ToString();
    string var2 = DatenPacket[0].ToString();
    string var3 = DatenPacket[0].ToString();
    ...
}
```

All this works fine but now I have to run this hole process within a Background Agent
This Agent 'CWTaskAgent' looks like this:

```
protected override async void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    { 
        await DataLib.DataLib.Daten();

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        NotifyComplete();
    }
```

Following a tutorial I have this code within the App.xaml.cs...:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
        string taskName = "CWTaskAgent";

        PeriodicTask oldTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(taskName) as PeriodicTask;

        if (oldTask != null)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Remove(taskName);
        }

        PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask(taskName);
        task.Description = "Change Livetile";

        ScheduledActionService.Add(task);

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        }
    }
```

...and this code within the WMAppManifest.xml:

```
<ExtendedTask Name="CWTaskAgent">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="CWTaskAgent" Source="CWTaskAgent" Type="CWTaskAgent.ScheduledAgent"/>  
  </ExtendedTask>
```

So and now if I run this within the emulator I get two errors after 10 sec or so, when the Agent is starting...

1. An exception (first chance) of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll.
2. An exception (first chance) of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessExceptio' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll.

The marked line is 'var TestTile = new Tiles();' within DataLib.cs

UPDATE: Code for reading and writing files:

```
using (Mutex mutex1 = new Mutex())
            {
                mutex1.WaitOne();
                try
                {
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream WritingStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TagMonatJahr.txt", FileMode.Create, DatenDateien);
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(WritingStream);
                    writer.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy"));
                    writer.Close();

}
finally
    {
        mutex1.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}


using (Mutex mutex2 = new Mutex())
{
mutex2.WaitOne();
try
{
    IsolatedStorageFileStream ReadingStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("TagMonatJahr.txt", FileMode.Open, DatenDateien);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ReadingStream);
    TagMonatJahr = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
}
    finally
    {
        mutex2.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: The structure you describe looks OK, but I'd like to see the code that  actually writes and reads the IsoStore (in DataLib).  Could the file names be computed differently in the app and in the background process?  What happens if both processes are running at "almost" the same time?

Comment: I have added the code - the mutex should avoid access at same time

Comment: Mutex looks good. I agree with crea7or, the UserControl requires you use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, and that probably explains UnauthorizedAccessException.  But FileNotFoundException?  How are you initializing 'DatenDatien'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/b1ebb388-78c7-4209-9692-8790d53f8128/backgroundtask-usercontrol-bug?forum=wpdevelop). It looks like you are trying to use UI code without dispatcher. So, try this code:

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{ 
 Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( async () =>
 {
      await DataLib.DataLib.Daten();
      NotifyComplete();
 });
}
```

Comment: I get directly two errors with this code 1."lambda expression" can not be converted to type 'System.Delegate "because this is not a delegate type. 2. The 'Await' operator can be used only in an async lambda expression. Where appropriate, highlight those lambda expression with the 'async' modifier

Comment: Yeah thanks - it seams to work - no errors and the lockscreen change after 10 sec. - but only one time - is this the right working of LaunchForTest?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Next time it will be launched after 30 mins or so.